# How to add custom query filters in WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-query, users, wp-user-query

I am creating a list of all users in wordpress.
For that I am using WP_User_Query with meta_query so that I can show only filtered users.
I am stuck where I want to add a custom query filters in SELECT

```
p.distance_unit
             * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(mt30.meta_value ))
             * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(mt31.meta_value))
             + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(mt30.meta_value)))) AS distance
```

and a custom JOIN

```
SELECT  '.$_REQUEST['user_lat'].'  AS latpoint,  '.$_REQUEST['user_long'].' AS longpoint,
            '.$_REQUEST['geo-radius'].'.0 AS radius,      111.045 AS distance_unit
) AS p ON 1=1
```

and a custom WHERE condition

```
AND (mt30.meta_value
 BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
     AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
AND mt31.meta_value
 BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
     AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)))))
```

and custom having clause

```
having distance < $_REQUEST['geo-radius']
```

I know that how we add query filters for POSTS but I am not able to add query filters for USERS

Please guide me or any reference url.

Thanks

Comment: Mayby try with custom field parameters? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Through custom field parameters you can use custom fields that you created through code and exist in DB. But I am looking to add new field in "select", add "join" and add having clause  dynamically before query run same as we can do for POSTS query. Any idea?

Comment: There is no way to add custom filter in WP User Query according to my question. So finally I write normal SQL and use custom paging function and display data through for loop.
Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

The [pre_user_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/) action hook in WordPress will allow you alter the SQL statements in the WP_User_Query object before they are run against the database.  Note, this is an action, not a filter, so there's no need to return the `$user_query` that gets passed in.

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'add_my_custom_queries' );

function add_my_custom_queries( $user_query ) {

   $user_query->query_fields .= ', my_custom_field ';  // additional fields 
   $user_query->query_from .= ' INNER JOIN my_table '; // additional joins here
   $user_query->query_where .= ' AND field='value' '; // additional where clauses
   $user_query->query_orderby .= ' ORDER BY my_custom_field '; // additional sorting
   $user_query->query_limit .= ''; // if you need to adjust paging

}
```