# WP CLI - show users whose ID is larger than given ID

Tags: wp-cli, wp-user-query

The below code achieves what i need for given ID = 200.

```
    wp user list --role='customer' --orderby=ID --order=asc | awk 'FNR == 1 
{next} $1>200 {print ;}'
```

How to do it with [wp user list](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/list/) and [WP User Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work with existing WP-CLI commands is through the [`WP_CLI::runcommand()`](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/internal-api/wp-cli-runcommand/).

Here are two examples how we can filter an existing WP-CLI command, namely the `wp user list` command based on `WP_User_Query` and it's `pre_user_query` hook:

### Run a custom script in WP-CLI

Let's write our `script.php` file with:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_pre_user_query' );

WP_CLI::runcommand(
    'user list --role=customer --orderby=ID --order=asc',
    [ 'launch' => false ]
);

remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_pre_user_query' );

/**
 * Modify WP_User_Query WHERE part.
 */
function wpse_pre_user_query( $user_query ) {
   global $wpdb;
   $user_query->query_where .= " AND {$wpdb->users}.ID > 200 ";
}
```

where we run the command in the current process with `'launch' => false` to make the current filtering possible. Here we use the `pre_user_query` as explained in the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228487/26350) by Pete Nilson.

We could also have grabbed the parsed json output from the command to work with it if needed:

```
$json = WP_CLI::runcommand(
    'user list --role=customer --orderby=ID --order=asc',
    [ 'launch' => false, 'parse' => 'json', 'return' => true ]
);
```

Then we can run it from the command-line with:

```
wp eval-file script.php
```

### Run a custom command in WP-CLI

Another approach would be to write a [custom command](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/commands-cookbook/) with [`WP_CLI::add_command()`](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/internal-api/wp-cli-add-command/) to support:

```
wp user wpse_list_query --gt_user_id=200
```

where the command part is `user wpse_list_query` with the `--gt_user_id` argument to only fetch users with a user ID that is greater than a given value.

Here's a plugin skeleton for that:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
    /**
    * Custom User List Query Command.
    *
    * [--gt_user_id=<user_id>]
    * : Greater than a given user ID.
    *
    * @when before_wp_load
    */
    $wpse_command_callback = function( $args, $assoc_args ) {
        if ( isset ( $assoc_args['gt_user_id'] ) ) {
            $uid = $assoc_args['gt_user_id'];
            WP_CLI::add_wp_hook(
                'pre_user_query', 
                function ( $user_query ) use ( $uid ) {
                    global $wpdb;
                    $user_query->query_where .= $wpdb->prepare(
                        " AND {$wpdb->users}.ID > %d",
                        $uid
                    );
                },
                $priority = 10,
                $accepted_args = 1
            );
        }
        WP_CLI::runcommand(
            'user list --role=customer --orderby=ID --order=asc',
            [ 'launch' => false ]
        );
    };
    WP_CLI::add_command( 'user wpse_list_query', $wpse_command_callback );
}
```

Note the PHPDoc is used to define the optional parameters and when to run this. If we skip the brackets in:

```
* [--gt_user_id=<user_id>]
```

then the argument is no longer optional.

Hope you can adjust this further to your needs!

Comment: what does the line `remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'add_my_custom_queries' );` do? and what is *add_my_custom_queries*? did you mean *wpse_pre_user_query*?

Comment: thanks, yes and we remove the action callback after the first  `WP_CLI::runcommand()` to make sure it will not affect the `WP_User_Query` of possibly other  `WP_CLI::runcommand()` that we might add to the script file.